# How to create reference to an objcect and initialize it as a child class with conditinal operator?

Tags: c++, reference, conditional-operator

```
#include<iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual bool isB() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B() { }
    bool isB() {std::cout << " not B\n"; return true;}
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C() { }
    bool isB() {std::cout << " not B\n"; return false;}
};
int main() {
    B b;
    A& a = (b.isB()) ? a(B()) : a(C()); // here is the problem
}
```

I also tried to make it as static cast to pointer of child class but it seems to not work as well. In real code myfunction takes A reference as a parameter and the condition depends on other part of code.

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is `a` anyhow?

Comment: The problem is it's not compiling :D  The error is:  no match for call (A)(B)

Comment: Does it help to use `A* a; if (b.isB()) { a = new B; } else { a = new C; } a->isB();`? But I suggest you revisit the basics of virtual functions and polymorphism. The above snippet should make the code compile, but it's not any useful IMO.

Comment: It wouldn't work regardless of ternary operator, you are trying to bind a non-const reference to a temporary object.

Comment: suppose you had only one branch and even adding the `const` then `const A& a = a(B());` would be still wrong. Why is there `a` on the right side of the `=` ?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. This is definitely an XY problem. If you can explain what real problem you're trying to solve -- no, not the one about initializing a reference like this but the real problem to which you believe the solution is to initialize a reference like this -- then it's very likely that the right solution, that fixes the real problem, will be found.

Comment: First of all you don't have a correct constructor in A. You would need constructors accepting an B or a C class (or run into ugly things like object slicing). 
So to get something referring to or pointing to A (interface) you need to construct a B or a C directly. To get your lifetime right and use A's polymorphism you will need to do this: `std::unique_ptr<A> = (b.IsB()) ? std::make_unique<B>() : std::make_unique<C>();`

Comment: But all in all it is indeed unclear WHAT you want to do.

Comment: @andreee I was thinking along the same lines, but I would not use naked new/delete. But use std::make_unique instead. It is time we teach people to use those smart pointers they are there for a reason :)

Comment: Maybe my question was not good. So I got interface A and classes B and C derived form it. I pass to method other object that has knowledge about what kind of object is A. And base on that I want to initialize it, so i can use methodes that are not common for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create either a `B` or a `C` instance, depending on `a.isB()`, where `a` is a given reference to `A`. `a` can reference either a `B` or a `C` instance.

Creating an instance of `B` or `C` based on `a` is easy:

```cpp
if (a.isB()) {
    B b;
} else {
    C c;
}
```

The above code is not very useful. You want to have a valid `A&` referencing the instance you just created. In C++ you cannot create a `A&` and instantiate a derived object at the same time. Reference must always reference something that exists. So your code cannot work. Also, any reference to A that references either `b` or `c` existing after the if-statement will be a dangling reference: Once you exit the scope of either branch the instance gets destructed.

As a consequence, you would have to work with pointers, ideally smart pointers. You could write a function

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<A> create(bool createB){
    if (createB) {
        return std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    else {
        return std::make_unique<C>();
    }
}
```

that returns an `std::unique_ptr<A>` from a `B` or `C` instance, depending on the input variable `createB`.

In your code, you could call it like this:

```cpp
B b;
auto x = create(b.isB());
A& xref = *x;
```

Keep in mind, that the variable `x` must outlive `xref`. Otherwise `xref` is a dangling reference and using it is undefined behavior.

Note that the function accepts a bool, not `A const&`. I personally prefer this style, because the signature `std::unique_ptr<A> create(A const& a)` does not properly convey the intent. I would be confused by this. If you have more than two derived classes, you could have `create` accept an enum, where each value corresponds to a derived class.

Here is the full code: https://godbolt.org/z/EEqPMvhdE